# Skycons are not visible in my Javascript application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, icons

The Skycons (animated Javascript icons) are not being displayed on my pen in codepen. They are being accessed but are not visible. [Here is the link to my pen.](https://codepen.io/prathiksha/pen/Vjzayx?editors=0110)

```
var skycons = new Skycons({"color": "pink"});

skycons.add("icon-animated", Skycons.CLEAR_DAY);

skycons.play();`
```

Comment: Have you included the skycaps.js file somewhere accessible? I'm having a similar problem :)